# String palindrom check

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I'm currently trying to write a function that will check how many palindroms words are in a given string and return that number to main.
My approach was to check the length of a string and copying into another in reverse and then comparing both.
While checking each time I reach a blank space

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrom(char str1[81]);

int main(){

    char str[81];
    gets(str);
    printf("%d pali\n", palindrom(str));


}


int palindrom(char str[81]) {

    int i, j=0, k = 0, pali_count = 0, length = 0, flag=0;
    char rev[81], c;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){}//getting the string length

    while (i >= 0) {//revrsing the string 
        rev[j++] = str[--i];
    }
    rev[j-1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", rev);


    length = j - 2;
    k = length;
    j = 0;
    while (k >= 0) {
        k--;
        j++;
        c = rev[k];
        if (rev[k] != str[j])
            flag++;
        if (c == ' ') {
            if (flag == 0)
                pali_count++;
            flag = 0;
            continue;
        }

        return pali_count;

    }





    return 0;

}
```

Comment: and what is the question/problem ?

Comment: ok but what's the question, or where is the problem

Comment: I assume he doesn't get correct number of palindrome.

Comment: Well the problem is it wont work . Somthing in my check is flaw and i cant figure ou what. Also i cant use any libary function like strcpy and the likep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of mistakes in your code. Let me explain you one by one:

- In `while loop` (where you check reverse string with current string) you return `pali_count` after one iteration which always be zero.
- If your last word is a palindrome word it never give you as palindrome because there is no space in your last word.
- And at last your whole algorithm is wrong. Check the below example:

  > Suppose, str = 'sabuj'
  >
  > after reverse the word it will be: rev = 'jubas'
  >
  > now if you check last char with first char then all char will be same hence it give you wrong result. you need to check first char with first char not with first with last as you already reverse the string.
  >
  > Here you will also face another problem in case of sentence like `mahedi sabuj` will be checked into `jubas ideham` which is also wrong because here we match first word with second word and vice versa.

Now Here is the solution:

- Split the sentence with `space`
- take each word is that palindrome
- if yes increase the count

Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrom(char str1[81]);

int main(){

    char str[81];
    gets(str);

    int result = 0;

    char *p = strtok(str, " "); // split word by space

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        result += palindrom(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }


    printf("%d pali\n", result);
}


int palindrom(char str[81])
{

    int i, j=0, k = 0, pali_count = 0, length = 0, flag=0;
    char rev[81], c;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){} //getting the string length

    while (i >= 0)  //revrsing the string
    {
        rev[j++] = str[--i];
    }

    rev[j-1] = '\0';

    length = j - 2;
    k = length;
    j = length;

    while (k >= 0)
    {
       if (str[j] != rev[k])
         return 0;

       k--;
       j--;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**Sample I/O:**

madam mm sabuj --> 2 pali

sabuj --> 0 pali

Comment: Well i cant use string.h libary function and i dont really know how to use pointers but thank you very much !

Comment: @GalElmaleh, I update the answer with explanation, you can check.

Comment: And about splitting word you can run a for loop check if you found a space then check the word before space and again start iterating and do the space process. [You need to add a space after last char of your inputted string like `str = str + ' '`

Comment: Thank you very much i think im on the right direction now thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `gets`, use [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 81

int is_palindrome(char *word);

int
main(void) {
    char str[STRSIZE];
    size_t slen;
    char *word;
    const char *delim = " ";
    int ispal = 0;

    printf("Enter some text: ");
    if (fgets(str, STRSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot read text into buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(str);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (str[slen-1] == '\n') {
            str[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Too many characters entered.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (!*str) {
        printf("No text entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    word = strtok(str, delim);
    while (word != NULL) {
        if (is_palindrome(word)) {
            ispal++;
        }
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    printf("%d palindromic words found.\n", ispal);
    return 0;
}

int
is_palindrome(char *word) {
    int start, end;

    if (!word) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (strlen(word) == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    start = 0;
    end = strlen(word) - 1;
    while (start < end) {
        if (word[start++] != word[end--]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Javatips {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = in.next();
        int n = x.length();
        boolean isPalindrom = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2 - 1; i++) {
            if (x.charAt(i) == x.charAt(n - 1 - i)) {
                isPalindrom = true;
            } else {
                isPalindrom = false;
            }
            if (isPalindrom) {
                System.out.println("the String " + x + " is palindrom");
            } else {
                System.out.println("the String " + x + " is not palindrom");
            }
        }
    }
}
```